# include of any Eigen 3.3.1 files in fresh Visual Studio project won't compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen

I created a fresh C++ (empty) project in VS2015, and then placed the Eigen 3.3.1 source code in an 'inc' folder in solution dir, such that the path to Matrix.h, for example, is *inc/Eigen/Core/*. I have set this *inc/* path as an additional include directory, and have also tried with *inc/Eigen/* as another include directory in case the files had issues including each other, but this changed nothing.

In main.cpp, I have the following:

```
#include "Eigen/Core/Matrix.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me, when compiling for x64:

```
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(18): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(18): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(18): error C2059: syntax error: '<'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(19): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(19): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(179): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
1>  c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(404): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar,_Rows,_Cols,_Options,_MaxRows,_MaxCols>' being compiled
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(186): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(186): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(186): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(192): error C2653: 'Base': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(192): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(192): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(192): warning C4183: 'EIGEN_DENSE_PUBLIC_INTERFACE': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(192): error C3646: 'PlainObject': unknown override specifier
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(194): error C2653: 'Base': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(195): error C2653: 'Base': is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(206): error C3646: 'EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE': unknown override specifier
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(206): error C3646: 'Matrix': unknown override specifier
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(206): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '&'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(206): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(207): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(223): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(237): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(243): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE'
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(259): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
1>c:\users\brody\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\eigentest\inc\eigen\core\matrix.h(14): fatal error C1075: the left brace '{' was unmatched at the end of the file
```

Which complains about line 18 of Matrix.h:

```
#ifndef EIGEN_MATRIX_H
#define EIGEN_MATRIX_H

namespace Eigen {

namespace internal {
template<typename _Scalar, int _Rows, int _Cols, int _Options, int _MaxRows, int _MaxCols>
struct traits<Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols> > // line 18
{
private:
// etc...
```

Similar issues occur with any other Eigen #include. Have I missed some required #include ordering or some compile flag or setting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must copy the entire `Eigen` directory not just the `src` subfolder. And you must not include files from the `src` subfolder directly, but include the files in the `Eigen` directory. E.g., `#include <Eigen/Core>` will include all core functionality, `#include <Eigen/Dense>` will include all dense functionality (this includes Core, Geometry and the decompositions).