# Seems to be a lot of syntax errors in .h files that are within Eigenvalues directory of Eigen library?

Tags: c++, matlab, c-preprocessor, eigen, mex

the file `mx_minimum_power.cpp` is located in the following directory:

```
D:\thesis library.Data\ALOS-PALSAR 12x2\San Francisco L 12x2
```

and 14 header files are located in the following directory:

```
D:\thesis library.Data\ALOS-PALSAR 12x2\San Francisco L 12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues
```

so the relative path is `Eigen\Eigenvalues` and I've included them in the preprocessor as follows:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexSchur.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexSchur_LAPACKE.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\EigenSolver.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\GeneralizedEigenSolver.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\GeneralizedSelfAdjointEigenSolver.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\HessenbergDecomposition.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\MatrixBaseEigenvalues.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\RealQZ.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\RealSchur.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\RealSchur_LAPACKE.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\SelfAdjointEigenSolver.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\SelfAdjointEigenSolver_LAPACKE.h"
#include "Eigen\Eigenvalues\Tridiagonalization.h"

using std::complex;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace Eigen;

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *arraysizePtr = NULL;
    arraysizePtr = mxGetPr(prhs[9]);
    const int arraysize = (int)*arraysizePtr;
    const int matrixDimention = 3;
}
```

now when I type the following in the matlab command window:

```
mex -g mx_minimum_power.cpp
```

I get the following:

```
Building with 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Professional'.
Error using mex
mx_minimum_power.cpp
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(20) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
';' before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(20) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(20) : error C2065: 'MatrixType' :
undeclared identifier
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(20) : error C2923:
'Eigen::internal::HessenbergDecompositionMatrixHReturnType' : 'MatrixType' is not a valid
template type argument for parameter 'MatrixType'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(21) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
';' before '{'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(21) : error C2447: '{' : missing function
header (old-style formal list?)
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(74) : error C2146: syntax error : missing
';' before identifier 'Index'
        d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
        12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(279) : see reference to class
        template instantiation 'Eigen::HessenbergDecomposition<_MatrixType>' being compiled
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(74) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(74) : error C2868:
'Eigen::HessenbergDecomposition<_MatrixType>::Index' : illegal syntax for using-declaration;
expected qualified-name
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(82) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
';' before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(82) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(82) : error C2238: unexpected token(s)
preceding ';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(85) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
';' before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(85) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(85) : error C2653: 'CoeffVectorType' : is
not a class or namespace name
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(85) : error C2238: unexpected token(s)
preceding ';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(119) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(119) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
',' before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(152) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(152) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
',' before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(179) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(179) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
';' before '&'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(180) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(183) : warning C4183:
'householderCoefficients': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning
'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(234) : error C2146: syntax error : missing
';' before identifier 'matrixQ'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(234) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(235) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(240) : warning C4183: 'matrixQ': missing
return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(270) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(270) : error C2238: unexpected token(s)
preceding ';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(271) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
';' before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(271) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(271) : error C2238: unexpected token(s)
preceding ';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(272) : error C2061: syntax error :
identifier 'CoeffVectorType'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(276) : error C2146: syntax error : missing
';' before identifier 'm_hCoeffs'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(276) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(277) : error C2146: syntax error : missing
';' before identifier 'm_temp'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(277) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(294) : error C2061: syntax error :
identifier 'CoeffVectorType'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(340) : error C2143: syntax error : missing
',' before '<'
        d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
        12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(368) : see reference to class
        template instantiation
        'Eigen::internal::HessenbergDecompositionMatrixHReturnType<_MatrixType>' being
        compiled
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(363) : error C2146: syntax error : missing
';' before identifier 'rows'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(363) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(363) : warning C4183: 'rows': missing
return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(364) : error C2146: syntax error : missing
';' before identifier 'cols'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(364) : error C4430: missing type specifier
- int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h(364) : warning C4183: 'cols': missing
return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(65) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'<'
        d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
        12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(260) : see reference to class template
        instantiation 'Eigen::ComplexSchur<_MatrixType>' being compiled
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(65) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(65) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(66) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before
identifier 'Index'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(66) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(66) : error C2868:
'Eigen::ComplexSchur<_MatrixType>::Index' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected
qualified-name
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(74) : error C2065: 'RealScalar' : undeclared
identifier
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(74) : error C2923: 'std::complex' : 'RealScalar' is
not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(81) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(81) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(81) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(113) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(113) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before
'<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(138) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(138) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'&'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(139) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(143) : warning C4183: 'matrixU': missing return type;
assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(162) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(162) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'&'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(162) : error C2086: 'const int
Eigen::ComplexSchur<_MatrixType>::ComplexMatrixType' : redefinition
        d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
        12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(138) : see declaration of
        'Eigen::ComplexSchur<_MatrixType>::ComplexMatrixType'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(163) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(166) : warning C4183: 'matrixT': missing return type;
assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(191) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(191) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before
'<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(217) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before
identifier 'info'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(217) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(218) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(221) : warning C4183: 'info': missing return type;
assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(248) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before
identifier 'm_matT'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(248) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(248) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
','
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(248) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(250) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before
identifier 'm_info'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(250) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(259) : error C2947: expecting '>' to terminate
template-argument-list, found '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(259) : error C2993:
'Eigen::ComplexSchur<_MatrixType>::NumTraits' : illegal type for non-type template parameter
'IsComplex'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(259) : error C2990:
'Eigen::internal::complex_schur_reduce_to_hessenberg' : non-class template has already been
declared as a class template
        d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
        12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(20) : see declaration of
        'Eigen::internal::complex_schur_reduce_to_hessenberg'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(259) : error C2079: 'Eigen::Scalar' uses undefined
struct 'Eigen::internal::complex_schur_reduce_to_hessenberg'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(259) : error C2433: 'Eigen::Scalar' : 'friend' not
permitted on data declarations
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(259) : error C2059: syntax error : '>'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(259) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'>'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(259) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(319) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./ComplexSchur.h(319) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before
'<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(62) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
before '<'
        d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
        12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(255) : see reference to class template
        instantiation 'Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver<_MatrixType>' being compiled
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(62) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(62) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding
';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(63) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'Index'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(63) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(63) : error C2868:
'Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver<_MatrixType>::Index' : illegal syntax for using-declaration;
expected qualified-name
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(71) : error C2065: 'RealScalar' : undeclared
identifier
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(71) : error C2923: 'std::complex' : 'RealScalar'
is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(78) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(78) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(78) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding
';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(85) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(85) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding
';'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(126) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(126) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ','
before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(157) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(157) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
before '&'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(158) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(162) : warning C4183: 'eigenvectors': missing
return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(182) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(182) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
before '&'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(183) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(186) : warning C4183: 'eigenvalues': missing
return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(213) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(213) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ','
before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(219) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'info'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(219) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(220) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(223) : warning C4183: 'info': missing return
type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(245) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'm_eivec'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(245) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(246) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'm_eivalues'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(246) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(250) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
before identifier 'm_matX'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(250) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(253) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(253) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ','
before '&'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(261) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(261) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ','
before '<'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(287) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int
assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexEigenSolver.h(287) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ','
before '&'
d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\Eigen\Eigenvalues\ComplexSchur_LAPACKE.h(84) : error C2065: 'Matrix' : undeclared
identifier
```

Is this true??? Eigen full of syntax errors?(200 errors here)!!!

Comment: What happens if you completely remove Eigen includes from your project? Does it compile?

Comment: @jpo38 yes, it does. if I convert all the 14 headerfile include lines and also the line `using namespace eigen`to comments

Comment: replace "\" by "/" in your includes

Comment: Maybe one of those headers above "Eigen\Eigenvalues\" define some macro definitions with names identical to those used in Eigen library?

Comment: @YSC doesn't make any difference

Comment: Your first error is in HessenbergDecomposition.h. looking at the source: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/HessenbergDecomposition_8h_source.html, it seems that this file assumes that Eigen::internal::trait<> has been priorly defined (notice how it doesn't include anything else). I'd guess you are missing a common Eigen include before your specific Eigenvalues inclusions.

Comment: @Frank I don't know but please have a look to [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html#details) and [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html).

Comment: Have you tried adding `#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>` before the other Eigen includes (or even instead of them), as these two links suggests?

Comment: @Frank didn't make any difference

Comment: I think your installation of Eigen is wrong. You must copy/install the entire `Eigen` directory, not just the `src` directory. Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404917/include-of-any-eigen-3-3-1-files-in-fresh-visual-studio-project-wont-compile

Comment: @chtz I did. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJIYP.png) is my Eigen directory. you see not just `src` folder but the whole `Eigen` folder has been copied to `D:\thesis library.Data\ALOS-PALSAR 12x2\San Francisco L 12x2` directory after extraction. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOG35.png) is where my `mx_minimum_power.cpp` file is located. It is just in `D:\thesis library.Data\ALOS-PALSAR 12x2\San Francisco L 12x2`. So the relative path to the files in Eigen directory and not the src directory will be `Eigen/Eigenvalues`.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gtuq.png) is my C++ code. I have written `#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>` in line 6 and finally [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEnkj.png) is what I get from compiling the MEX file in MATLAB

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJIYP.png contradicts your first error messages as `d:\thesis library.data\alos-palsar 12x2\san francisco l
12x2\eigen\eigenvalues\./HessenbergDecomposition.h`, etc should not exist. Please edit your question to what your actual setup is

Comment: @chtz ok, I will. but please let me just a few days to fulfill my project and then I'll come and will get my posts neat and maybe will add some answers to several of them

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to directly include `Eigen/src/...` files, but rather include:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
```

See this doc [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html#title0).

Comment: in that case, I'll get the error no such file or directory. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430558/how-to-add-header-files-path-relative-to-the-current-file) it is

Comment: Perhaps I state the obvious, but may it be a problem with defining the Eigen location to the include path? If it complains that is no such file or folder is either because it actually doesn't exist or it is not correctly defined in the include path.